# Zabbix - UserParameter Powershell script item is 'not supported' - CPU per process monitoring

Tags: windows, powershell, process, cpu-usage, zabbix

I'm new to zabbix and I'm trying to create custom User Parameter to Monitor CPU utility per process(Windows Machine).

I have a powershell script and a user parameter, I also added a new item under zabbix -> Configuration -> hosts, but I keep getting the *Not Supported* status and I ran out of potential blogs/solutions to help me.

Does anyone have an idea on what I'm missing / doing wrong ?

My user Parameter : `UserParameter=checkcpuperprocess[*], C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\Zabbix\conf\CPUperProc.ps1`

My powershell script :

```perl
    $properties=@(
        @{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},
        @{Name="CPU (%)"; Expression = {$_.PercentProcessorTime}},   
        @{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.workingSetPrivate / 1mb),2)}}
    )
    Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process |
        Select-Object $properties |
        Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: did you tried to use `checkcpuperprocess` key? (without `[*]`)

Comment: Yeah, it's not working either. I think I'm missing something but I can't identify what exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have enabled UnsafeUserParameters in Zabbix Agent config file.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks bro